# Updating WordPress publish posts dates using cron-job

Tags: php, wordpress, date, cron

I was looking for help in a particular topic in WordPress in which I haven't worked before. I'm unable to get how to work

with cron-job and its settings.

There are Three posts in WordPress, now these three posts are event posts which is showing event name, event day, event date and event time.

I need to work only with "**event date**". After doing a bit research stuffs I found that I need to setup a cron job in the

three posts for updating the "event date" fields.

In these three posts following are their respective datas from which I only need to work with "**event date**" which is the

only section which is important for me at the present moment.

Event 1 Name :- HEALING NIGHT
Event 1 Date :- February 21, 2020
Event 1 Day :- Friday
Event 1 Time :- 7:30 pm

Event 2 Name :- SUNDAY CHURCH SERVICE
Event 2 Date :- February 23, 2020
Event 2 Day :- Sunday
Event 2 Time :- 10:00 am

Event 2 Name :- PRAYING TOGETHER
Event 2 Date :- February 25, 2020
Event 2 Day :- Tuesday
Event 2 Time :- 7:30 pm

Now for these three events there are 3 posts as I mentioned earlier. I am explaining by taking an event for example and then explaining all 3 events alongside.

In the first event the "**Event 1 Date**" is "**February 21, 2020**". I need to setup a cron-job (as per my thinking) for automatically updating the "**Event 1 Date**" as **NEXT SEVENTH DAY** just after 12:00 AM (midnight of February 21, 2020) i'e it **AUTOMATICALLY GETS UPDATED** to the "Event 1 Date :- **February 28, 2020**" and then automatically to "Event 1 Date :- **March 6, 2020**" and so on. This process will run with respect to all the three posts accordingly.

Like for example for the second event the next "event date" will be "Event 2 Date :- **March 1, 2020**" and then "Event 2 Date :- **March 8, 2020**" and so on.

Like for example for the third event the next "event date" will be "Event 2 Date :- **March 3, 2020**" and then "Event 3 Date :- **March 10, 2020**" and so on.

All these dates and day will be with respect to **Australian Standard time Zone**.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are talking about an "event date" field. What exactly is this - the regular post date, or a meta field added by some plugin? If it comes from a plugin, please specify which plugin it is. This will be important to know where to get the date from and what format to use. Also, are you able to set up real cron jobs on your hosting / server? Because WP cron jobs are a bit limited since they only execute when someone visits your page. It can still be done with WP cron jobs, however, a little more logic is required then.

Comment: @Damocles - For the mean time i'm open to suggestions. I haven't tested any plugins yet, though i've found one plugin which might work, i'm not sure, and for the mean time first I ned to test it locally in the local server then i'll switch onto hosting account. any help ?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't asking you to install a plugin - I wanted to know where the "event date" comes from (either the normal post date, or it is added by some already installed plugin). You have to enter or select the date somewhere and I wanted to know where. The thing is: we must programmatically find those 3 posts, get the value of the event date from each, check if they're in the past, and add 7 days if it expired. This itself is easy, but I have no idea where and how this date is stored. To understand this was the point of my question.

Comment: @Damocles - The  "event date" will be the post published date. The cron need to setup in such a manner that the same post gets updated every next 7days automatically (individually for each of the three posts). Which means that the next time whenever the next event occurs the "Event date" i.e the particular post will get updated and hence, therefore showing the updated date as the next "event date". I hope that makes sense ?

Answer (score 0):

First, this code will look up the 3 posts by name - this is ugly. It would be prettier to create a category (e.g., Events) and add only these 3 posts to the category. This way they could be looked up by category rather than by name.

The code will do the following:

1. in a daily cron, look up those post's IDs
2. fetch their post date and see if they are older than today
3. if older, add 7 days to the date until date is after today
4. update the post date with the new date

```
function mycron_event_dates()
{
  $post_names = array('HEALING NIGHT', 'SUNDAY CHURCH SERVICE', 'PRAYING TOGETHER');
  foreach ($post_names as $post_name) {
    $post_id = post_exists($post_name);
    if ($post_id) {
      $post = get_post($post_id);
      $post_datetime = $post->post_date;
      $post_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($post_datetime)); // without time
      $date_now = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(current_time('mysql'))); // right now
      $date_changed = false;
      while ($post_date < $date_now) {
        $post_new_date = strtotime("+7 day", strtotime($post_datetime));
        $post_date = date('Y-m-d', $post_new_date);
        $post_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $post_new_date);
        $date_changed = true;
      }
      if ($date_changed) {
        update_post(array(
          'ID' => $post_id,
          'post_date' => $post_datetime,
        )); // modify the post date
      }
    } else {
      error_log("Event schedule: post '$post_name' not found");
    }
  }
}

add_action( 'init', 'mycron_setup_cron');

function mycron_setup_cron()
{
  if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'mycron_event_dates' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( strtotime(date('Y-m-d')), 'daily', 'mycron_event_dates' );
  }
}
```

You will have to try around with this and see if it actually finds the `$post_names` (otherwise, it will output an error in the debug log. They have to precisely match the real post names. If this doesn't work, you can try replacing this with an array of post IDs and do a

```
$post_ids = array(1111, 2222, 3333); // replace by real post IDs of the events
foreach ($post_ids as $post_id) {
```

loop instead. To test this, you can just add a direct call to `mycron_event_dates()` into the `mycron_setup_cron` function so it gets called on every page load for debugging purposes. As soon as it works, you can remove it and leave it to the cron job.

Comment: Thanks kind heartedly mate for the help. I'll run a check and will let you know if there is any problem. I hope that works for you...?

Comment: Since i'll run the cron-job once every week so I'm confused a bit about what you wrote here :-
add_action( 'init', 'mycron_setup_cron');

function mycron_setup_cron()
{
  if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'mycron_event_dates' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( strtotime(date('Y-m-d')), 'daily', 'mycron_event_dates' );
  }
}

Comment: And the below code i was looking for suggestion :-

function weekly_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules[ 'weekly' ] = array( 
        'interval' => 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,  // 604,800, seconds in a week
        'display' => __( 'Weekly' ) );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'weekly_cron_schedule' );

Comment: You have dates spread across the week - or to be more precise, 5 days. You have three dates, e.g. Feb. 21, Feb 23, and Feb 25. If it happens to run on Feb 22 (**weekly**), you will only increase the date of Feb 21+7 days = Feb 28. The other two dates remain the same for another week and will update on Feb 29.. This cannot be what you want. This means your visitors will see expired events until shortly before the new event.

Comment: WordPress default Cron seems to be not working properly ... need to check it in a LIVE Server after configuring the cron-job there. Can you send me a screenshot how to configure it in the live server the exact way which is required. I've gone through the cron section in the cpanel and there are mentioned periods or time intervals about when I want to fire the cron-job. I was a little bit confused about the scheduling thing.\

Comment: Hey, @Damocles, can we stay in touch through any social media platform just for knowledge followup. Will be delighted to meet you.